# Length of string in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to check the length of string, but it is not working, can anyone please help me to find what I'm doing wrong?

HTML is

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl"> 
<form novalidate> First Name:<br> <input type="text" ng-model="user.firstName"><br>
<button ng-click="check()">RESET</button> 
</form> <p>form = {{user}}</p> </div>
```

And JS is

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.check = function() {
        var arr = $scope.user;
        if (arr.length<=3){
            $scope.user="enjoy"
        }

    };
    $scope.check();
});
```

Comment: Define "is not working". Where does the $scope.user come from? How can you get the length of something that you haven't defined anywhere?

Comment: I have tried that but its not working

Comment: Check my answer now it is exactly working as you expect. Since you did not added the HTML i misunderstood $scope,user as a variable instead it is a JSON object.

Comment: Don't say "it is not working" and leave it at that. Describe the behavior and explain how it differs from what you expect. Without further information, the question will be closed as "unclear".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't declared `$scope.user` in your controller and calling the `check()` function. Doing this will give you

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

So you need to declare the `$scope.user` as

```
$scope.user= {
  firstName : ''
};
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl"> 
<form novalidate> First Name:<br> <input type="text" ng-model="user.firstName"><br>
<button ng-click="check()">RESET</button> 
</form> <p>form = {{user}}</p> </div>
```

So your controller becomes like this

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('formCtrl', function($scope){
   $scope.user= {
     firstName : ''
   };

  $scope.check = function() {
    var arr = $scope.user.firstName;
    if (arr.length<=3){
        $scope.user.firstName="enjoy"
    }

  };
  $scope.check();
})
```

For your simplicity and work around here is the link to [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/paLvqg2n/1/)

Comment: What do you mean. Post your HTML.

Comment: <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">
  <form novalidate>
    First Name:<br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.firstName"><br>
   
    <button ng-click="check()">RESET</button>
  </form>
  <p>form = {{user}}</p>
  
</div>

Comment: Check my answer now it is exactly working as you expect. Since you did not added the HTML i misunderstood $scope,user as a variable instead it is a JSON object.

Comment: Could you please mark it and up vote it so that others will know it really helped you

Comment: And always remember to handle variables value properly in AngulaJS. Usually we tend to make silly mistakes.

Comment: Thanks AKA one another question,  for checking empty string if  arr =='' " works but why arr.length ==0 doesn't work?

Comment: If your  var arr = $scope.user.firstName; then arr.length ==0  should work

Comment: Could you please green mark the answer and up vote it.